# Sun 2nd, 3rd, 4th largest only if greater than 2

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have the following formula:
=Max(Large(A1:A4,2)-2,0)+Max(Large(A1:A4,3)-2,0)+Max(Large(A1:A4,4)-2,0)

Can this formula be simplified?

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Simplified? According to what metric? Number of characters?

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Let's say that your 2nd, 3rd and 4th largest values are 2, 3 and 4. Should the total be 9? As written, your total would be 3, since you've subtracted 2 from each. And since you only have four values in the range, wouldn't it be simpler to just eliminate the single MAX value and then sum what's left?

Comment: The correct answer, using your example, is 3. But a better example is 1, 3 and 4. The answer here is also 3, because any number less than 2 is to be ignored (or, in mathematical terms, treated as 0).

Comment: Yes, simplified = fewest number of characters

Answer (score 1):

May be for a whole column

```
=sum(ARRAYFORMULA(Large(if(A1:A>2,A1:A,0),{2,3,4})-2))
```